# What is the most exact translation of the Greek word δωρεάν?

Tags: greek, john, word-study, translation-philosophy

I came across this word most notably when reading the book of John where it says

> But this is to fulfill what is written in their Law: ‘They hated Me without reason.’ **John 15:25 BSB**

The word δωρεάν here is translated to "without a cause" or "without cause". Yet in other passages, δωρεάν, is translated to "in vain" or, in another case, "freely". 
Εxamples among others are Galatians 2:21, Matthew 10:8, and Revelation 22:17. Are all these uses just a result of the context surrounding the word usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

δωρεάν, like its Hebrew equivalent חִנָּם (*chinnam*), possesses positive and negative connotations; its meaning is dependent on the context.

It can mean “freely,” as in Numbers 11:5:

> We remember the fish that we ate in Egypt **freely**...
>   ...זָכַרְנוּ אֶת הַדָּגָה אֲשֶׁר נֹאכַל בְּמִצְרַיִם **חִנָּם**
>   ἐμνήσθημεν τοὺς ἰχθύας οὓς ἠσθίομεν ἐν Αἰγύπτῳ **δωρεάν**

It can also mean “without cause,” as in Job 1:9:

> Then Satan answered Yahveh and said, “Does Job fear God **for no reason**?”
>   וַיַּעַן הַשָּׂטָן אֶת יָהְוֶה וַיֹּאמַר **הַחִנָּם** יָרֵא אִיּוֹב אֱלֹהִים
>   ἀπεκρίθη δὲ ὁ διάβολος καὶ εἶπεν ἐναντίον τοῦ κυρίου μὴ **δωρεὰν** σέβεται Ιωβ τὸν θεόν

If there were one English word that could possibly capture the entire range of meaning, it would be “gratuitously.”

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, **gratuitously**:

> 1. Without cost to the recipient; without any claim or merit on his part; free of charge.
> 2. Without sufficient cause, reason, or ground; unjustifiably, unwarrantably, unnecessarily.

Comment: (+1)  It's probably worthwhile mentioning that the Hebrew is relevant because the Gospel is quoting a Hebrew text (Ps 35:19 / 69:5). (I suspect that this is a distinctively Jewish usage set forth by the LXX; in classical Greek it appears to mean "as a gift".)

Answer (score 0):

According to BDAG, δωρεάν is the accusative of δωρεά.

δωρεάν is used as an adverb with the following meanings (according to BDAG):

1. "Pertaining to being freely given, *as a gift, without payment, gratis*", eg, Matt 10:8, Rev 21:6, 22:7, 2 Cor 11:7, Rom 3:24.
2. "Pertaining to being without contributory fault, *undeservedly, without reason/cause*", eg, John 15:15 (alluding to Ps 34:19, 68:5 LXX ref)  See also, PsSol7:1, cp Ps 118:161, etc.
3. "Pertaining to being without purpose, *in vain, to no purpose*", eg, Gal 2:21, Job 1:9, Ps 34:7 (LXX ref).

My Analytical lexicon of the Greek New Testament by Friberg et al gives similar results.